# Django: different access types for different urls

Tags: python, django, localhost, django-urls, remote-access

In my Django project, I defined my URLs in urls.py file as below:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include('page1.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include('page2.urls')),
    url(r'^remote/', include('registering.urls')),   
]
```

with ALLOWED_HOSTS definition in settings.py file, both /remote and /api has the same access from type, so if ALLOWED_HOSTS is

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

So both /api and /remote URLs are remotely accessible.

But if ALLOWED_HOSTS is:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']
```

So both  /api and /remote URLs are not remotely accessible, and are accessible only from localhost.

But what I need is that only /remote URLs are remotely accessible. And /api should be accessible only from localhost and not allowed to access from remote.
I there an idea to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider creating a decorator on your views that will return 403 status depending on the host:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def host_check():
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.META['HTTP_HOST'] in settings.YOUR_REMOTE_ALLOWED_HOSTS:
                return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            raise PermissionDenied()
        return wrapper
     return decorator
```

and in your views:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from . import 

@method_decorator(host_check, name='dispatch')
class SomeAPIView(APIView):
```

Also, I do remember there was [a module](https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this purpose but I'm not sure if it's still support lates Django version.